# Adding wildcard to map URI in dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am looking to handle mapping of uri in dispatcher servlet to serve all the file extensions in a particular folder .Right now I am adding the mappings manually in the dispatcher servlet like this :

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.PNG</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Is there any way I can handle all using a special url pattern which will map any extension in a particular folder rather than adding all extensions manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try do this ?

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>       
        <url-pattern>*.PNG</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: no, but looking to avoid manually specifying extensions .Rather want to  have something which will take any extension without explicitly specify it like above.

Comment: I see something like this (?i)\.(jpg|png|gif)$. But you have to find the good regex that corresponds to what you want